# Background blur is alway on in video conferences when using Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Since a few weeks in all the Video conferences that I participate using Google Chrome, my background is blurred. No matter conferencing service I use Meet, MS Teams or Whereby in all of them the background is automatically blurred out. **The blur option is disabled in all of  those tools**. So, it is coming from Chrome, I verified it.

This happens only in Google Chrome, (as wells as Chrome Incognito mode where there are no extension) Regardless of the Camera, or meeting solution used in Chrome, same result. On the other hand, Safari and Zoom work without a blur.

In the image you can see Chrome, Safari, and Camo Studio(the Video Source).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post trying to find a solution to this same problem, and it ended up being that macOS had blur enabled for Chrome via “Portrait mode”. Originally found on [this article](https://www.macworld.com/article/917739/use-portrait-mode-on-mac.html#), try going to control center in the top macOS menu bar and then under Video Effects see if Portrait mode is enabled, and if so disable it.